# AS3 Full Screen script, video crashed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I load external video with playback component (skin over play stop seek mute vol.swf), its working great but when I use

`fscommand("fullscreen", "true");`

on my first scene (first keyframe in timeline), and after that when I reach my video scene. I got just black screen

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `fscommand()` to set fullscreen mode when the `Stage` already offer the functionality ? 
fscommand() can't be used in web players, and is not recommended for AIR apps.
If there isn't, you should try using Stage.displayState instead : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState